# Disable Scrolling When Clicking on a Link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML markup, which is just three tabs which when clicked, display pre-loaded text in a div on the page,

```
    <a class="page" id="tab1">This is tab!</a> 
    <a class="page" id="tab2">This is tab 2!</a> 
    <a class="page" id="tab3">This is tab3!</a>
```

This jQuery simply hides or shows text when one of the tabs are clicked,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $(".page").hide(); 
   $("#tab1").show(); 
}); 
$(".page").click(function() { 
   var id = $(this).attr("href"); 
   $(".page").hide();
   $(id).show(); 
});
```

However, if there is page overflow (i.e. the page is scrollable) when I click on one of the tabs, the page auto-scrolls to center the div in the viewport. How do I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: where is `href` in your `<a>` tag?

Comment: There are no hrefs. I was lazy. :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To prevent the **page scroll on click** (following anchor hash) use: [**Event.preventDefault()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
$(".page").click(function( evt ) {

   evt.preventDefault();       // prevents browser's default anchor behavior

   // Other code here....
   $(".page").hide();            // HIDE ALL     .page
   $("."+ this.id ).show();      // SHOW RELATED .(id)
});
```

Answer (score 12):

```
 <a href="#" class="page" id="tab1" onclick="return false;">This is tab!</a>
```

Add `return false` to all your anchors.

Comment: this is the **wrong** way to do this, check my answer or Roko's answer

Comment: Wrongggg. If you use an anchor you MUST use href property, not onclick!

Comment: I've didn't notice that href attribute is missing. I don't think that it's a wrong way.

Comment: This is the older javascript way. Still valid in some situations I guess ?

Comment: I think, it's valid. By the way, you can easily use roXon's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for links with hash. What you want is to prevent the default browser behavior, so you should use the `event.preventDefault` method

```
$(".page").click(function( event ) { 
   var $el = $(this), id = $el.attr( "href" ); 
   $(".page").hide();
   $el.show(); 
   event.preventDefault();
});
```